# How to replace values from JSON with those found by RegEx in a file using Python?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-2.7, web.py

Lets say there's a file in the filesystem which contains values preprended with `$`.

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: $name01</li>
    <li>Age: $age01</li>
</ul>
```

Am able to obtain the values via RegEx:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import re

with open("person.html", "r") as html_file:
    data=html_file.read()   
list_of_strings = re.findall(r'\$[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*', data)
print list_of_strings
```

This prints the values into a list:

```
[$name01, $age01]
```

Now, I send a JSON sample payload to my web.py server like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"Joe", "age":"25"}' http://localhost:8080/myservice
```

I'm able to obtain these values like this:

```
import re
import web
import json

urls = (
    '/myservice', 'Index',
)

class Index:
    def POST(self):
        data = json.loads(web.data())

        # Obtain JSON values based on specific keys
        name = data["name"]
        age = data["age"]
```

Question (s):

1. How can I obtain the JSON values from the payload iteratively and put them inside a list (instead of manually obtaining them by key name)?
2. Once I have this list, how can I replace the values in the HTML file with the JSON values in the list?

e.g.

How do I manually insert these items in the HTML file (in accordance with the RegEx exp that was defined above):

Replace $name01 with name?

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: Joe</li>
    <li>Age: 25</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin Guan,

Thanks for your solution but unfortunately it didn't work.

Here's how I got it working (data is the json content):

```
def replace_all(output_file, data):
    homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
    contracts_dir = homedir + "/tmp"
    with open(output_file, "r") as my_file:
        contents = my_file.read()
    destination_file = contracts_dir + "/" + data["filename"]
    fp = open(destination_file, "w")
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        contents = contents.replace("$" + str(key), value)
    fp.write(contents)
    fp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my way(maybe here's a better way to do this):

```
import re
import json

html = """
<ul>
    <li>Name: $name01</li>
    <li>Age: $age01</li>
</ul>"""

JSON = '{"name01":"Joe", "age01":"25"}'
data = json.loads(JSON)

html = re.sub(r'\$(\w+)', lambda m: data[m.group(1)], html)

print(html)
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: Joe</li>
    <li>Age: 25</li>
</ul>
```

By the way, I'd prefer use Template like Jinja2. Since I don't know about web.py, so I can't give an example. But I found the document: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor